# Заменить значение столбца, содержащего выражение, результатом этого выражения

Tags: python, строки, pandas, split

Есть столбцы в которых содержатся значения следующего типа "85+2".
Хотелось бы заменить такое значение следующим - "87".

Выполняю следущий код:

```
import pandas
import seaborn as sns

data = pandas.read_csv('players_20.csv')
data['value_eur'] /= 1000000

def best_pos(df):
  idx = [' ls', ' st', ' rs', ' lw', ' lf', ' cf', ' rf', ' rw', ' lam', ' cam', ' ram', ' lm', ' lcm', ' cm', ' rcm', ' rm', ' lwb', ' ldm', ' cdm', ' rdm', ' rwb', ' lb', ' lcb', ' cb', ' rcb', ' rb']
  tot = []
  for i in idx:
    hemi = df[i].split('+')
    total = int(hemi[0])+int(hemi[2])
    tot.append(total)
    return tot

data.apply(best_pos)
```

Происходит ошибка компиляции, не понимаю в чем проблема.

[Исходный датасет](https://github.com/georgemartynov/fifa_data).

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе небольшой (3-5 строк) пример входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить из него в итоге? Вы пишете: « Происходит ошибка компиляции, не понимаю в чем проблема» - без полного error traceback вам тут врядли смогут помочь

Comment: Если вы не приводите пример того, что хотите получить в результате, то тем, ктот пытается вам помочь приходится угадывать. В случае если мы не угадали - мы вам не помогли и потратили впустую наше и ваше время.

Comment: На будущее: приводите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @ЕгорМартынов Вы зря игнорируете советы по улучшению вопроса. Я, например, отказался проголосовать (+) за ваш вопрос потому, что в текущем виде он безполезен для кого-либо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если суть вопроса в том как вычислить арифметическое выражение в столбцах, то это можно сделать так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\players_20.csv")

col_idx = (df.columns == "ls").argmax()

r = (df
     .iloc[:, col_idx:]
     .dropna()
     .apply(lambda x: x.str.split("+", expand=True)
                       .rename(columns={0:"a", 1:"b"})
                       .astype(int).eval("a+b")))
```

---

результат:

```
In [44]: r
Out[44]:
       ls  st  rs  lw  lf  ...  lb  lcb  cb  rcb  rb
0      91  91  91  95  95  ...  65   54  54   54  65
1      94  94  94  92  93  ...  64   56  56   56  64
2      87  87  87  93  92  ...  64   49  49   49  64
4      86  86  86  92  91  ...  64   52  52   52  64
5      85  85  85  90  90  ...  76   69  69   69  76
...    ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ..  ...  ..  ...  ..
18273  34  34  34  33  33  ...  47   48  48   48  47
18274  35  35  35  35  34  ...  48   49  49   49  48
18275  45  45  45  45  45  ...  49   51  51   51  49
18276  45  45  45  47  46  ...  50   51  51   51  50
18277  44  44  44  46  45  ...  50   52  52   52  50

[16242 rows x 26 columns]
```

---

исходные данные:

```
In [45]: df.iloc[:, col_idx:]
Out[45]:
         ls    st    rs    lw    lf  ...    lb   lcb    cb   rcb    rb
0      89+2  89+2  89+2  93+2  93+2  ...  63+2  52+2  52+2  52+2  63+2
1      91+3  91+3  91+3  89+3  90+3  ...  61+3  53+3  53+3  53+3  61+3
2      84+3  84+3  84+3  90+3  89+3  ...  61+3  46+3  46+3  46+3  61+3
3       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4      83+3  83+3  83+3  89+3  88+3  ...  61+3  49+3  49+3  49+3  61+3
...     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
18273  32+2  32+2  32+2  31+2  31+2  ...  45+2  46+2  46+2  46+2  45+2
18274  33+2  33+2  33+2  33+2  32+2  ...  46+2  47+2  47+2  47+2  46+2
18275  43+2  43+2  43+2  43+2  43+2  ...  47+2  49+2  49+2  49+2  47+2
18276  43+2  43+2  43+2  45+2  44+2  ...  48+2  49+2  49+2  49+2  48+2
18277  42+2  42+2  42+2  44+2  43+2  ...  48+2  50+2  50+2  50+2  48+2

[18278 rows x 26 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас "происходит ошибка", то нужно приводить ее текст в вопросе.

Если вам нужно просто сложить числа в колонках, то попробуйте сделать так (обратите внимание на список с названиями колонок - в них НЕТ пробела:

```
cols = idx = ['ls', 'st', 'rs', 'lw', 'lf', 'cf', 'rf', 'rw', 'lam', 'cam', 'ram', 'lm', 'lcm', 'cm', 'rcm', 'rm', 'lwb', 'ldm', 'cdm', 'rdm', 'rwb', 'lb', 'lcb', 'cb', 'rcb', 'rb']
for i in cols:
    df[i].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df[i] = df[i].apply(lambda x: eval(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в вашем коде ошибка просто в индексации, правильно так:

```
hemi = df[i].split('+')
total = int(hemi[0])+int(hemi[1]) # 1, а не 2
```

Потому что тот символ, по которому происходит разбиение функцией `split`, в выходной список не попадает:

```
print('85+2'.split('+'))
['85', '2']
```

И в данном случае вообще можно на индексы не завязываться, а преобразовывать в числа и суммировать все элементы списка разом, тогда это будет работать и для более длинных вариантов, например '423+23+343+34':

```
print(sum(map(int, '423+23+343+34'.split('+'))))
823
```

Comment: вот бы научиться читать мысли таких топикстартеров ;)

Comment: @MaxU Иные рабочие техзадания выглядят не сильно понятнее ))